# convergence of $\sum_{n≥ 1}\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+2)}{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+5)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine if the series converges, to do this I apply the ratio criterion as follows

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+3)}{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+6)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{{\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+2)}{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+5)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}}=\left(\frac{\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+3)}{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+6)}\right)}{{\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+2)}{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot\cdot\cdot(n+5)}\right)}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

If I am not mistaken, this limit tends to one, so I could use Raabe's criteria to arrive at something concrete, but I am not entirely sure. Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Hint: first, cleaning the same terms in the numerator and the denominator, you will have $a_n=\sqrt{\frac{24}{(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}}$, and work from this to decide whether is converges.

Comment: What I did was to find a series that is above it, this series converges, therefore I can conclude that the series I am studying converges? (using basic comparison criteria)

Comment: Yes, you can do so. For example, you can find $a_n<5n^{-3/2}$ and this is converging